# Перекрытие двух объектов.

Tags: android

Необходимо, чтобы один объект View перекрывал другой объект View. (В моём случае это два ListView). Объекты должны находится, как бы в разных плоскостях. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Вот ответ: [Placing/Overlapping(z-index) a view above another view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182486/placing-overlappingz-index-a-view-above-another-view-in-android).

Comment: Используя фреймЛайоут или РелейтивЛайоут, один листВью "просвечивает через другой". а нужно, чтобы не просвечивало.

Comment: Назначь бекграунд со 100%-ной опасити

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout вам в помощь. Отлично перекрываются объекты без доп. Либ.

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayout или RelativeLayout с background

Например:

```
<FrameLayout
     android:width="match_parent"
     android:height="match_parent">

     <View
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:height="match_parent"/>

     <View
         android:width="match_parent"
         android:height="match_parent"
         android:background="#fff"/>

<FrameLayout
```